# To have the number of the page in all pages

Tags: numbering, page

I am writing a report and the number of the page is only on the first page of each chapter.

How could I do?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\setlength\textwidth{145mm}
\setlength\textheight{247mm}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\evensidemargin{15mm}
\setlength\topmargin{0mm}
\setlength\headsep{0mm}
\setlength\headheight{0mm}
\let\openright=\clearpage
 \pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{headers},

%% Generate PDF/A-2u
\usepackage[a-2u]{pdfx}

%% Character encoding: usually latin2, cp1250 or utf8:
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%% Prefer Latin Modern fonts
\usepackage{lmodern}

%% Further useful packages (included in most LaTeX distributions)
\usepackage{amsmath}        % extensions for typesetting of math
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % math fonts
\usepackage{amsthm}         % theorems, definitions, etc.
\usepackage{bbding}         % various symbols (squares, asterisks, scissors, ...)
\usepackage{bm}             % boldface symbols (\bm)
\usepackage{graphicx}       % embedding of pictures
\usepackage{fancyvrb}       % improved verbatim environment
\usepackage{natbib}         % citation style AUTHOR (YEAR), or AUTHOR [NUMBER]
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % makes sure that bibliography and the lists
                % of figures/tables are included in the table
                % of contents
\usepackage{dcolumn}        % improved alignment of table columns
\usepackage{booktabs}       % improved horizontal lines in tables
\usepackage{paralist}       % improved enumerate and itemize

\hypersetup{unicode}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}

% Definitions of macros (see description inside)
\include{macros}

% Title page and various mandatory informational pages
\begin{document}
\include{title}
\tableofcontents
\input{acknowledgement.tex} 
\input{abstract.tex} 

\include{preface}
\include{chap01}
\include{chap02}
\include{chap03}

\include{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The code is not compilable. We do not know what you are inputting. Besides, I get an error compiling without the input files: undefined pagestyle (line 11). Can you show the 'preamble' of your input files?

Comment: The default pagestyle for `report` is `plain` which puts the page number in the foot. You have specified `\pagestyle{headers}` which you have not defined. Did you mean `\pagestyle{headings}`? Maybe don't specify and pagestyle.